# What to choose: Xubuntu or Xfce Session?

Tags: 14.04

When logging in I can choose to use Xubuntu or Xfce. Besides the font (it's a little blurry in Xfce) and Xfce seemingly using a little bit less memory than Xubuntu (which is not an issue) they look exactly the same to me. What's the difference? And which one is faster?

Comment: @fossfreedom: it does not answer the question which one's faster

Comment: "which is faster" is not something that can be readily answered - its basically asking for an opinion which would not make a good Q&A.  The rest of your question is an exact match.

Comment: @fossfreedom I thought speed can be proved somehow maybe.